# How to organize casperjs test with es6 modules

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Is there a way to use ES6 modules to organise the test for CasperJS, and if not what is the normal way to organise the tests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `patchRequire` method to include your CasperJs module.

Documentation: [Writing CasperJS modules](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/writing_modules.html)